# How to get value of selected listview item jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have this

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="selecionarPaisPreferencia" class="select">Pais</label>
  <select name="selecionarPaisPreferencia" id="selecionarPaisPreferencia">
    <!--Aca Se Cargan Dinamicamente Los Paises En las preferencias-->
  </select>
</div>
```

and the elements are dinamically loaded like this

```
for (i = 0; i < paises.length; i++) {
  $("#selectPaisConsulta").append('<option data-pais="'+paises[i]+'">'+paises[i]+'</option>');
}
```

the elements get loaded correctly
there is a preference menu where you choose a country and when y click accept y want to store the value that was selected in the listview
i have the atribute data-pais that stores the value if it is any help
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `.val` method

```
$("#selectPaisConsulta").val()
```

Comment: @user2651401 please mark this as the selected answer by choosing the "tick" mark below the upvote/downvote counter.